# How to delete a @ManyToMany association (joined link) without deleting the actual target entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring-MVC application and I have many-to-many mapping in it. There are 3 tables, one is GroupAccount, memberjunction, GroupMembers. Now, when I delete a groupMember, I only want to remove the entries from GroupMembers and memberjunction corresponding to the memberId. I tried to use Cascade.Remove, it caused deletion in the GroupAccount's as well. I am posting my sql code, and what I have till now.

SQL code :

```
CREATE TABLE groupaccount
(
  groupid numeric NOT NULL,
  groupname character varying,
  adminusername character varying,
  CONSTRAINT groupid PRIMARY KEY (groupid)
)
CREATE TABLE memberjunction
(
  memberid integer NOT NULL,
  groupid numeric NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT membergroupid PRIMARY KEY (memberid, groupid),
  CONSTRAINT groupaccount_memberjunction_fk FOREIGN KEY (groupid)
      REFERENCES groupaccount (groupid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT groupmembers_memberjunction_fk FOREIGN KEY (memberid)
      REFERENCES groupmembers (memberid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
CREATE TABLE groupmembers
(
  memberid integer NOT NULL,
  musername character varying,
  accesslevel boolean DEFAULT true,
  CONSTRAINT memberid PRIMARY KEY (memberid)
)
```

GroupMembersDAOImpl deletion method :

```
@Override
public boolean removeGroupMember(int memberId) {
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    GroupMembers groupMembers = (GroupMembers) session.get(GroupMembers.class, memberId);
    if(!(groupMembers == null)){
        groupMembers.getGroupAccounts().clear();
        session.flush();
        session.delete(groupMembers);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

GroupAccount entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupaccount")
public class GroupAccount {
 @Id
    @Column(name="groupid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "groupaccount_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupaccount_seq_gen",sequenceName = "groupaccount_seq")
    private Long groupId;
 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "memberjunction", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "groupid")},
                inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "memberid")})
    private Set<GroupMembers> groupMembersSet = new HashSet<>();

    public void setGroupMembersSet(Set<GroupMembers> groupMembersSet){
        this.groupMembersSet = groupMembersSet;
    }

    public Set<GroupMembers> getGroupMembersSet(){
        return this.groupMembersSet;
    }
}
```

GroupMembers Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupmembers")
public class GroupMembers {

 @Id
    @Column(name="memberid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "groupmembers_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "groupmembers_seq_gen",sequenceName = "groupmembers_seq")
    private int memberid;
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupMembersSet")
    private Set<GroupAccount> groupAccounts = new HashSet<>();

    public void setGroupAccounts(Set<GroupAccount> groupAccounts){
        this.groupAccounts = groupAccounts;
    }

    public Set<GroupAccount> getGroupAccounts(){
        return this.groupAccounts;
    }
}
```

Latest Error Log :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "groupmembers" violates foreign key constraint "groupmembers_memberjunction_fk" on table "memberjunction"
  Detail: Key (memberid)=(2501) is still referenced from table "memberjunction".
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
    org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
```

The above method fails to work, as it says, there is a reference to memberJunction. How can I query the memberJunction too and remove entries corresponding to the memberId. Any help would be nice. Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: You need to add your entities mapping too.

Comment: @VladMihalcea : Entities added... :-) Kindly let me know.. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
for(GroupAccount groupAccount : groupMembers.getGroupAccounts()) {
    groupAccount.getGroupMembersSet().remove(this);
}
groupMembers.getGroupAccounts().clear();
session.flush();
session.delete(groupMembers);
```

Because you have a `@ManyToMany` association, the association table is not available at runtime. For this you can either:

1. Clear the `GroupAccounts` from `GroupMembers` prior to deleting the GroupMembers. make sure you flush so that you make sure the delete action [doesn't prevent](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-knowing-flush-operations-order-matters/) an update against on the deletable entity state.
2. You can replace the `@ManyToMany` with a `@OneToMany` association to a `MemberJunction` entity (whose PK/@Id is build from both the `GroupMembers` and `GroupAccount`). This way you can cascade the delete from `GroupMembers` to the `MemberJunction` `mappedBy` Set, because it will delete the association table rows, and not the actual `GroupAccount` entities.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It didn't work. I am updating my post with the updated code and error log. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: Check my updated answer. You should set both sides of the associations, meaning you have to remove the deletable GroupMembers from the GroupAccount instances.

Comment: I used your updated answer, unfortunately, the same error. Do you require me to post some code, but it is the same what you have written.

Comment: You need to make sure the GroupMember is removed from all entities atached in your current Session. It can be in some other entities as well. That's why you get this error.

Comment: The only association GroupMember has is with the association table. I made sure of that for testing. The error says the same, entity is still referenced from memberJunction. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure the equals/hashCode are properly Set and debug the delete procedure I gave you to make sure the Accounts no longer reference the deleting Member.

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to flush the session after deleting the member. I still see an entry in association table, but the member is deleted. Any idea why I still see in association table an orphan entry???

Comment: Could it be because it's a link between some other Member (other than the one being deleted) and some Account?

Comment: Nope, It is a test platform, I have 2 users only. Nothing else. I will check. Thanks for your help, appreciate. :-)